# z-index issue with overlay

Tags: css

I am trying to add overlay but it is not working as expected.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.center-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-div">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="overlay">

</div>
```

I need the div with class center-div to be above div with class overlay..

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `.center-div` _is_ above `.overlay`

Comment: `.center-div` is already above the `.overlay`! Try adding `background-color` to `.center-div` to highlight it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.center-div` is already above the `.overlay`!.

Try adding `background-color` to `.center-div` to highlight it.

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.center-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-div">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="overlay">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's said it is `.center-div` is above `.overflow`

If you change the font color to white you will see that it is above the overlay

http://codepen.io/bryn/pen/GqEGzb